# Recurrence relations for the generalized Laguerre polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, special-functions, orthogonal-polynomials

We have the following recurrence relations for the generalized Laguerre polynomials $L_n^{k}$(.) ([Recurrence relations](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AssociatedLaguerrePolynomial.html))
$$L_n^k(x)= L_n^{k+1}(x) -L_{n-1}^{k+1}(x); \quad \forall k \in \mathbb N.$$
Is there a formula for 
$$L_n(x) - L_{n-1}(x) =?$$
where $L_n(x)$ are the Laguerre polynomials.

Note that, in terms of the Laguerre polynomials $L_n(x)$, we have 
$$ L_n^0(x)= L_n(x).$$

Answer (score 1):

The connection to be made is with the **kernel** associated with Laguerre polynomials.
More precisely, consider the following function called the Christoffel-Darboux formula:

$$K_n(x,y)=a \dfrac{L_{n}(x)L_{n+1}(y)-L_{n+1}(x)L_n(y)}{x-y}$$

that can be found in a more general form (see formula (5.1.11) p. 101)
in the essential (easily "downloadable") book by G. Szegö called "Orthogonal polynomials"  or in this [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomials).

(for a certain constant $a$ depending on $n$).

Indeed, taking $y=0$ (a case considered on page 102 of Szegö's book), as $L_n(0)=1$, this formula boils down to:

$$xK_n(x,0)=a(L_{n}(x)-L_{n+1}(x))$$

i.e.,

$$L_{n+1}(x)-L_{n}(x)=-\dfrac{1}{a}xK_n(x,0)$$

Remark: Christoffel-Darboux/kernel formulas exist for all families of orthogonal polynomials.

Comment: Thank you @JeanMarie. Just, It we can write $L_n(x) - L_{n-1}(x) = L_{n}^{-1}(x)$ ?

Comment: Why not ? But there could be a notational ambiguity (small risk of confusion with "the" inverse function of $L_n$ that does not exist in fact...)

Comment: So. the formula $L_n^{\alpha}(x)= L_n^{\alpha+1}(x) -L_{n-1}^{\alpha+1}(x);$ is true for all arbitrary real number $\alpha$ ?

Comment: ... with your notation, yes.

Comment: Interesting, are there other interesting applications of this powerful formula ?